# Is there a way to get the index of the median in python in one command?

Tags: python, math, numpy

Is there something like `numpy.argmin(x)`, but for median?

Comment: The title should have been "in Python" instead of "in numpy". I couldn't find it using google.

Comment: I can do np.argmin(np.abs(np.median(x) - x)), but was wondering if there is already a command.

Comment: As far as I know there is no single command that does this. Am I right you want something like `np.argmedian(array)` without any nested calculations?

Comment: Yes, I thought something might have existed. Guess not.

Comment: `np.median([1, 2])` returns 1.5.  How should `np.argmedian([1, 2])` be defined in this case?

Comment: I wonder why the question gets downvoted. Writing an `np.argmin` which works with any `axis=...` and any `keepdims=...` is not trivial.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: I think this be dealt with using a flag that would set whether you choose the lower or the upper of the two options for that case (with a default value). It seems like a natural addition to numpy, IMHO.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

a quick approximation:

```
numpy.argsort(data)[len(data)//2]
```

Comment: In general this has complexity n log(n) because it involves sorting. Finding the median only takes linear when you use Quickselect. Theoretically it would have lower complexity to compute the median first and then search for it, like @Hagay's answer.

Answer (score 15):

In general, this is an ill-posed question because an array does not necessarily contain its own median for numpy's definition of the median. For example:

```
>>> np.median([1, 2])
1.5
```

But when the length of the array is odd, the median will generally be in the array, so asking for its index does make sense:

```
>>> np.median([1, 2, 3])
2
```

For odd-length arrays, an efficient way to determine the index of the median value is by using the `np.argpartition` function. For example:

```
import numpy as np

def argmedian(x):
  return np.argpartition(x, len(x) // 2)[len(x) // 2]

# Works for odd-length arrays, where the median is in the array:
x = np.random.rand(101)

print("median in array:", np.median(x) in x)
# median in array: True

print(x[argmedian(x)], np.median(x))
# 0.5819150016674371 0.5819150016674371

# Doesn't work for even-length arrays, where the median is not in the array:
x = np.random.rand(100)

print("median in array:", np.median(x) in x)
# median in array: False

print(x[argmedian(x)], np.median(x))
# 0.6116799104572843 0.6047559243909065
```

This is quite a bit faster than the accepted sort-based solution as the size of the array grows:

```
x = np.random.rand(1000)
%timeit np.argsort(x)[len(x)//2]
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 25.4 µs per loop
%timeit np.argpartition(x, len(x) // 2)[len(x) // 2]
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 6.03 µs per loop
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer

Answer (score 12):

It seems old question, but i found a nice way to make it so:

```
import random
import numpy as np
#some random list with 20 elements
a = [random.random() for i in range(20)]
#find the median index of a
medIdx = a.index(np.percentile(a,50,interpolation='nearest'))
```

The neat trick here is the percentile builtin option for nearest interpolation, which return a "real" median value from the list, so it is safe to search for it afterwards.

Comment: the accepted answer `numpy.argsort(data)[len(data)//2]` is 3-4 times faster, but this one is still elegant :)

Comment: for `numpy.array` use `np.argwhere(a == np.percentile(a, 50, interpolation='nearest'))`

Comment: The basis of `percentile` is `partition`, which does this out of the box

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the indices with the elements (`zip`) and sort and return the element on the middle or two elements on the middle, however sorting will be `O(n.logn)`. The following method is `O(n)` in terms of time complexity.

```
import numpy as np

def arg_median(a):
    if len(a) % 2 == 1:
        return np.where(a == np.median(a))[0][0]
    else:
        l,r = len(a) // 2 - 1, len(a) // 2
        left = np.partition(a, l)[l]
        right = np.partition(a, r)[r]
        return [np.where(a == left)[0][0], np.where(a == right)[0][0]]

print(arg_median(np.array([ 3,  9,  5,  1, 15])))
# 1 3 5 9 15, median=5, index=2
print(arg_median(np.array([ 3,  9,  5,  1, 15, 12])))
# 1 3 5 9 12 15, median=5,9, index=2,1
```

Output:

```
2
[2, 1]
```

The idea is if there is only one median (array has a odd length), then it returns the index of the median. If we need to average to elements (array has even length) then it returns the indices of these two elements in an list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the accepted answer `numpy.argsort(data)[len(data)//2]` is that it only works for 1-dimensional arrays. For n-dimensional arrays we need to use a different solution which is based on the answer proposed by @Hagay.

```
import numpy as np

# Initialize random 2d array, a
a = np.random.randint(0, 7, size=16).reshape(4,4)
array([[3, 1, 3, 4],
       [5, 2, 1, 4],
       [4, 2, 4, 2],
       [6, 1, 0, 6]])

# Get the argmedians
np.stack(np.nonzero(a == np.percentile(a,50,interpolation='nearest')), axis=1)  
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 2]])

# Initialize random 3d array, a
a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=27).reshape(3,3,3)
array([[[3, 5, 3],
        [7, 4, 3],
        [8, 3, 0]],

       [[2, 6, 1],
        [7, 8, 8],
        [0, 6, 5]],

       [[0, 7, 8],
        [3, 1, 0],
        [9, 6, 7]]])

# Get the argmedians
np.stack(np.nonzero(a == np.percentile(a,50,interpolation='nearest')), axis=1) 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer `numpy.argsort(data)[len(data)//2]` can not handle arrays with NaNs.

For 2-D array, to get the median column index in the axis=1 (along row):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3.3, 4],
                   'b': [80, 23, np.nan, 88],
                   'c': [75, 45, 76, 67],
                   'd': [5, 4, 6, 7]})
data = df.to_numpy()
# data
array([[ 1. , 80. , 75. ,  5. ],
       [ 2. , 23. , 45. ,  4. ],
       [ 3.3,  nan, 76. ,  6. ],
       [ 4. , 88. , 67. ,  7. ]])

# median, ignoring NaNs
amedian = np.nanmedian(data, axis=1)
aabs = np.abs(data.T-amedian).T
idx = np.nanargmin(aabs, axis=1)
idx
array([2, 1, 3, 2])

# the accepted answer, please note the third index is 2, the correspnoding cell value is 76, which should not be the median value in row [ 3.3,  nan, 76. ,  6. ]
idx = np.argsort(data)[:, len(data[0])//2]
idx
array([2, 1, 2, 2])
```

Since this is a 4*4 array with even columns, the column index of median value for row No.3 should be 6 instead of 76.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification @jakevdp's answer which also has an optional axis input to take the argmedian along a specific axis:

```
def argmedian(x, axis=None):
    if axis is None:
        return np.argpartition(x, len(x) // 2)[len(x) // 2]
    else:
        # Compute argmedian along specified axis
        return np.apply_along_axis(
            lambda x: np.argpartition(x, len(x) // 2)[len(x) // 2],
            axis=axis, arr=x
        )
```