# find the median frequency of the resultant fft magnitude

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fft

I am having my head confused around  computing the median frequency from the fft I computed over my data, using the following function:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq

def fft_transfrom(data):
  # data has a 4D shape
  fourier = fft(data, axis=2)
  mag = np.round(np.abs(fourier), 0)
  fs = 5 # sample size
  freq = fftfreq(fs, d=1/fs)
  
  return mag, freq
```

And this sample data:

```py
A = np.array([
            [[[0, 1, 2, 3],
              [3, 0, 1, 2],
              [2, 3, 0, 1],
              [1, 3, 2, 1],
              [1, 2, 3, 0]]],
            
            [[[9, 8, 7, 6],
              [5, 4, 3, 2],
              [0, 9, 8, 3],
              [1, 9, 2, 3],
              [1, 0, -1, 2]]],
            
            [[[0, 7, 1, 2],
              [1, 2, 1, 0],
              [0, 2, 0, 7],
              [-1, 3, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 1, 0]]]
              ])
```

So I get the magnitude and frequencies like so:

```py
magnitude, frequency = fft_transfrom(A)

magnitude
array([[[[ 7.,  9.,  8.,  7.],
         [ 3.,  4.,  3.,  3.],
         [ 2.,  2.,  1.,  2.],
         [ 2.,  2.,  1.,  2.],
         [ 3.,  4.,  3.,  3.]]],


       [[[16., 30., 19., 16.],
         [11.,  7.,  7.,  2.],
         [ 6., 11.,  9.,  5.],
         [ 6., 11.,  9.,  5.],
         [11.,  7.,  7.,  2.]]],


       [[[ 1., 14.,  3., 10.],
         [ 2.,  4.,  2.,  6.],
         [ 2.,  7.,  1.,  7.],
         [ 2.,  7.,  1.,  7.],
         [ 2.,  4.,  2.,  6.]]]])
```

And sorted like so:

```py
sorted_magnitude = np.sort(magnitude, axis=2)

sorted_magnitude
array([[[[ 2.,  2.,  1.,  2.],
         [ 2.,  2.,  1.,  2.],
         [ 3.,  4.,  3.,  3.],
         [ 3.,  4.,  3.,  3.],
         [ 7.,  9.,  8.,  7.]]],


       [[[ 6.,  7.,  7.,  2.],
         [ 6.,  7.,  7.,  2.],
         [11., 11.,  9.,  5.],
         [11., 11.,  9.,  5.],
         [16., 30., 19., 16.]]],


       [[[ 1.,  4.,  1.,  6.],
         [ 2.,  4.,  1.,  6.],
         [ 2.,  7.,  2.,  7.],
         [ 2.,  7.,  2.,  7.],
         [ 2., 14.,  3., 10.]]]])
```

Now that each array column (instance column) are sorted.

But I have problem finding the frequency that corresponds to the middle of the sorted power spectrum

```py
median_frequency = frequency[np.where(magnitude ==  
       sorted_magnitude[int(len(magnitude)/2)])]

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 4 were indexed
```

How do I get the frequencies of the middle `magnitude` in each array.

2. I can directly get the median of each array in magnitude using:

```py
np.median(magnitude, axis=2)
array([[[ 3.,  4.,  3.,  3.]],

       [[11., 11.,  9.,  5.]],

       [[ 2.,  7.,  2.,  7.]]])
```

How then do I get the frequency corresponding to the median power spectrum?

Comment: What on earth is the point of sorting the magnitude?  That's like sorting the pixels in an image.  It doesn't produce useful information.  Even finding the median frequency doesn't necessarily make sense to me.  However, here are some suggestions:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923605/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-index-of-the-median-in-python-in-one-command

Comment: The shape of the magnitudes `(3, 1, 5, 4)` does not match the shape of the frequencies `(100,)`. I think there's some issue with the sampling? In the scipy examples, magnitude and frequency are the same shape of array: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.fft.html

Comment: @SNygard My bad. I edited this to the right sample size. The initial one was the actual size in my dataset. You are right! I make the necessary changes to match data size in the question.

Comment: If your data size often changes, you can use `fs = data.shape[2]` in the function to use the size of the array in axis 2.